# How to make a TextBlock of an UWP-Application update automatically?

Tags: xaml, uwp

I have a background-thread which updates a Integer-value once per second. How can I map this Integer to a Text-Field of my XAML form that the Form always shows the current value and updates automatically if the Integer changes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ViewModel with a binding.
With OnPropertyChanged() it will automatically changed and displayed in your UI.

here is an example to give you an idea

use in your xaml:

```html
<TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox" Text="{Binding Name}".../>
```

in your code behind:

```html
...
var vm = new ViewModel("Nr.7");
this.BindingContext = vm;
foreach(var x in Whatever)
{
    vm.Name = x;
}
```

```html
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace MyAppNamespace
{
  // This class implements INotifyPropertyChanged
  // to support one-way and two-way bindings
  // (such that the UI element updates when the source
  // has been changed dynamically)
  public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
      private string name;
      // Declare the event
      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

      public ViewModel()
      {
      }

      public ViewModel(string value)
      {
          this.name = value;
      }

      public string Name
      {
          get { return name; }
          set
          {
              name = value;
              // Call OnPropertyChanged whenever the property is updated
              OnPropertyChanged();
          }
      }

      // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event
      // The calling member's name will be used as the parameter.
      protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
      {
          PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you really much for this, I will check it out! Thanks!